VSCODE not showing documentation on hover for external libraries in python for ipynb files
Ok, everytime I import an external library(any external library) in an ipynb file, vscode doesn't show any documentation whatsoever for the external library functions(almost all the time). I have faced this issue multiple times, with almost any library.
For example,
suppose I import a library and use a method in the albumentations library that I installed from pip:

When I hover over it with mouse, it shows me this:

The library does indeed get imported correctly, and I can use its functions perfectly well. I just don't know why it doesn't show the documentation on hover.
Any idea how to get it to work with showing the full and proper documentation that I expect to see normally with any standard ide. I don't have this problem with intellij, and I expect this to work with vscode as well. Have I configured something wrong here? Is there some setting that should be enabled to get this to work? Why is it that it doesn't work with any external library that I install with pip?
Edit:
I am aware of doing A.Rotate? and getting the documentation, but I want to know how to do it with hover in particular because its a minimum level of convenience that I expect from an editor

The yellow squiggle under the import makes me think it can't resolve (find) that module (let us know what that error is, as it may help). Do you have more than one version of Python installed on this machine? And if so, have you selected the correct one as your interpreter in VS Code?

@JRiggles I am using a virtual environment. Yes there are multiple python environments on this machine. I have been using the same python environment in my ipynb file that I pip installed the library in, everything works fine and runs, but the documentation doesn't show on hover. Is there some vscode setting I have to change to enable this?

The language server treats the workspace root (i.e. folder you have opened) as the main root of user module imports. This means that if your ipynb imports are not relative to this path, the language server will not be able to find them.
These extra roots must be specified to the language server. The easiest way to do this (with the VS Code Python extension) is to create a workspace configuration which sets python.autoComplete.extraPaths.
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./src"]
}

This list may also be configured using thePYTHONPATH environment variable, either set directly, or via a .env file in the workspace root (if using the Python extension):
PYTHONPATH=./src

is it possible that since some of the libraries are not stored in the base or default env, that its not able to find the documentation for them?
